# fancyhdr: missing section number of bibliography

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

I know there are other questions like this, but I didn't find an answer for my particular question.

Please consider the MWE below. While the section number is included in the header for the first chapter, it isn't for the bibliography. I used `renewenvironment` to prevent the bibliography to create an own section becaues I need a section number and an entry in the ToC.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1008-2849,
  author        = {Jan Wassenberg and Peter Sanders},
  title         = {Faster Radix Sort via Virtual Memory and Write-Combining},
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprintclass   = {cs.DS},
  eprint        = {1008.2849},
  date          = {2010-09-06},
  pages         = {1-8},
}
\end{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     { %\section{\bibname}% <-- this line was commented out
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{first section}
some content
\nocite{*}
\newpage
\section{Bibliography}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Do you know what I could change to include the chapter number as well in the fancyhdr title for the bibliography? It is displayed correctly in all other chapters.

Comment: Please post a Minimal (non-)Working Example.

Comment: @cfr you were right, I added a MWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the right way to have a numbered bibliography in KOMA classes. You can simply add the option `bibliography=totocnumbered` when loading `scrartcl`:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
```

If you want to change the title of the bibliography from "References" to "Bibliography" add the following line in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}}
```

Moreover, the usage of `fancyhdr` with KOMA classes is discouraged. Use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead, which is designed for these classes.

The `fancyhdr` part of your preamble can be substituted by:

```
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1008-2849,
  author        = {Jan Wassenberg and Peter Sanders},
  title         = {Faster Radix Sort via Virtual Memory and Write-Combining},
  eprinttype    = {arxiv},
  eprintclass   = {cs.DS},
  eprint        = {1008.2849},
  date          = {2010-09-06},
  pages         = {1-8},
}
\end{filecontents}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
some content
\nocite{*}
\newpage
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't know about `scrlayer-scrpage`

Comment: @muffel You're welcome. KOMA classes have their way for customizing the layout of the document which is much better than standard classes, IMHO. :-)